# How to make Sonic Pi play a specific buffer after boot?

Tags: headless, sonic-pi

I made a theremin using the instructions on [raspberrypi.org](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/ultrasonic-theremin). I want to be able to use this as a real instrument i.e. I only need to power on the Pi and everything will work without using a screen and a keyboard to click play after opening Sonic Pi.

I'm aware that Sonic Pi is a GUI application, so it will need the desktop to be up and running, but with autologin I don't think it's a problem. I know how to autostart the Python script and Sonic Pi, but I don't know how to make Sonic Pi to play the necessary buffer after autostarting.

Answer (score 0):

Sonic Pi can run also in headless mode, the server is write in Ruby and you can control it via OSC UDP Commands.

Let's research on Google Sonic PI Server, it does not require a full desktop at all.